# Class method decorator with a generic class method

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator

I am trying to get a class method decorator that works just fine with a normal class method to work with a generic class method.

I have this code [typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAg6geygawFMoAhNAhAbwCgEFlsBzACgDo3goGBXAWwIDsIYAPoAuBF355+2AO78A2gF0AlJRq0k2fmGzICLesw7c+gkSoDcGgL5U7VWNsgIwAB2D8EAXg0AeDVoAFQALAEsMAgAPCAEAEwwcfCJSMAIAGkCEIJMCRGjY-gSEJghwsHFQiPSENhYTXgEhMQkpGXllNW8APgQABShsHgiCP0lpOX5uzNpupi7ujVLciEqVmqdBAvEAYVR0AFk8kOw4gBECJxgIXB3tWJi-KrAanM487oWstABPflgEAAzSTwMLaBBQAhuVCwAhmCBHMqnJhZWhlCKVcozTS0Oq4MIMML8YDIACCnEa5nE43aiiUWTU1BxaPKhkYTAUAHJYCT9HFOTV0WAWJtIFAuPBcCxiXwNvcCtLgHxVNZmRC8lwoF4ICsRbzSljamx8YTiWSKfCwFYsjZrI59hgAKIxIj8AhJQhQBAFeKJXCe1LkJkIAAC7k88w0bkGsXgBDiCF+-wQDDyfgAShqtXNGVlIRBNV5JHECICifHExgaZNKwhMwWtaqEHYbEA):

```js
abstract class WorkerBase {
  log(...arguments_: unknown[]) {
    console.log(arguments_);
  }
}

const span =
  <
    This extends WorkerBase,
    Target extends (this: This, ...arguments_: unknown[]) => Promise<unknown>,
  >() =>
  (target: Target, context: ClassMethodDecoratorContext<This, Target>) =>
    async function replacementMethod(
      this: This,
      ...originalArguments: unknown[]
    ) {
      this.log(['called', this.constructor.name, context.name]);
      return target.call(this, ...originalArguments);
    };

class ExterneWorker extends WorkerBase {
  @span()
  protected async get<Return>() {
    return undefined as unknown as Return;
  }
}
```

And compilation fails with:

```
Decorator function return type '(this: ExterneWorker, ...originalArguments: unknown[]) => Promise<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'void | (<Return>() => Promise<Return>)'.
  Type '(this: ExterneWorker, ...originalArguments: unknown[]) => Promise<unknown>' is not assignable to type '<Return>() => Promise<Return>'.
    Type 'Promise<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<Return>'.
      Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'Return'.
        'Return' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'unknown'.
```

The `span` decorator works just fine with a non-generic class method, but it fails with a generic one. I don't really understand what TypeScript is telling me. I think something is wrong with the `Return` definition in my span decorator definition.

Comment: So, is there a reason you have so many generics in `span()`?  Constraints aren't used as inference sites (see [ms/TS#7234](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7234)) so there's nowhere from which to infer `Return` or `Arguments`, so `Return` defaults to `unknown`.  TS doesn't have higher order generics, so even if you had an inference site, I think you'd see `unknown` for `Return`.  Personally I'd just do something like [this approach](//tsplay.dev/wE20bN) where you accept any method at all and then infer the types from it. Does that fully address the question or am I missing something?

Comment: ok, updated the example, I need to access stuff from the base class, and I need to access the name of the current class.

Comment: I don't see how that changes anything of substance, I'd do it [this way](https://tsplay.dev/mMLPbN), which is the same. Am I missing something?

Comment: Well, I was taught that when you use "any" you are just saying to typescript "don't bother I know what I'm doing" which feels wrong because then typescript can't tell you if you thought you knew and then got it wrong :(

Comment: The thing about `any` is that it's bivariant, which isn't type safe, but that only matters if something can go wrong.  Saying `new (...args: any) => any` means "this is a function" and there's no way that can go wrong, even in the face of generics. Can you demonstrate some particular issue that crops up when you use `any` in my suggested code?

Comment: No, I had to shut up a few typescript-eslint "never use any, never assign any and never return any" rules that we have, but I guess it is ok in this case. Plus, the actual code with all the things we do in there actually still works.

Comment: So, shall I write up an answer explaining my version and why it works where yours doesn't? And I won't worry too much about restrictions on `any` in my answer?  Or am I missing something still? (And if I do write an answer it will probably be tomorrow since it's very late in my time zone right now)

Comment: No, you are not missing anything, no, when using Promise<any> as the return type of the target, I get everything to work just fine, thank you. I still have to have a couple more generic types, but it is because the real workerbase class also has more generic types, and those don't enter into the equation here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is mostly that the type of the `get()` method is `<R>() => Promise<R>`, which means that it somehow returns *any type the caller wants*.  Such a method cannot possibly be implemented safely, and according to a sound type system, it is equivalent to `() => never`, where [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) is the [bottom type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_type) assignable to any other type.  This is exactly the *opposite* of [the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown).  So `() => unknown` is not assignable to the `get()` method type, and the compiler correctly balks.

As an example, if you can call `worker.get<string>()` and get a `Promise<string>`, and call `worker.get<number>()` and get a `Promise<number>`, that means that `worker.get()` at runtime somehow produces a `Promise` which is both a `string` and a `number`. This is impossible. There are no `string & number` values. It's equivalent to `never`.

---

If you want to use that type anyway, it means you need your `span()` to accept a method of any function type, even those unsafe ones like `() => never` and `<R>() => Promise<R>`. The easiest approach there is to use an unsafe *type*... [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any):

```
const span = <
  Target extends (...args: any) => Promise<any>,
>() =>
  (
   target: Target, 
   context: ClassMethodDecoratorContext<ThisParameterType<Target>, Target>
  ) =>
    async function replacementMethod(
      this: ThisParameterType<Target>,
      ...originalArguments: Parameters<Target>
    ) {
      console.log(['called', context.name]);
      return target.call(this, ...originalArguments);
    };

class ExterneWorker extends WorkerBase {
  @span() // okay
  async get<Return>() {
    return undefined as unknown as Return;
  }
}
```

This is the same as yours except that I use [the `ThisParameterType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#thisparametertypetype) utility type to compute the type you referred to as `This` instead of trying to infer it.

Yes, `any` is unsafe, but `(...args: any) => any` matches just about any function without worrying about the arguments or return type. Trying to make an `any`-free version is possible, but then it won't play nicely with already-unsafe types like `<R>() => R`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAg6geygawFMoAhNAhAbwQF8AoW2bAO0gTAAdgmEBeBAHloIEAFWBQA5gUQEAHhAJMAJhgAUAOk3iJYAFwIuATwDaAXQCUvAHwIAClGwBbAJZgC-I1YA0tK6ss8VkIIqhDa0vpiktJeSMwK8voAwqjoALLSABbYSgAiBIwwELhJ8XIQ-CKZrrbiwI7SRCKG7O5RUhDeouGdAUHCwmiGTLAIAGYAriMQzswIUATsqLAEDUwQGRDZSqrBAwhbrpHVYLUwDQpQza2VPd57A5rquM4SzkzAyACCkhNrEHo7HULkQwLdop0HpYKA9hIwWNhkAR1MhsBJVMYAOSwT5IpSY2LwhIQdQfBoWADcsPm0gmUG4YQh6hxyGQoROsSeLzeH2+v3+YHMVP21CpDFSGAAovIiEwCDh8EQEOVFCosLhCCQyJRggABDhcfzBIYjBAdfgAJVp9L80IeCwgdO4UyUBDG7wISgMGCmeCY2AA7tw0AgrY76cKaLQ6LQgA)